# How to pick freeze few records even if data frame gets updated daily

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have few dataset which get updated daily and I need to freeze few records based on some condition.

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | 01/01/2019 | NA |
| 2 | Y | 01/01/2019 | NA |
| 3 | N | 01/01/2019 | 01/02/2019 |

So if there is any date present in Col3 then Value in Col1 should get freeze. Suppose the data gets updated tomorrow and I ran the code again and the new data frame appears to be like this

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | 01/01/2019 | NA |
| 2 | N | 01/01/2019 | 02/02/2019 |
| 3 | Y | 01/01/2019 | 01/02/2019 |

So my final data frame should display result like this:

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | 01/01/2019 | NA |
| 2 | N | 01/01/2019 | 02/02/2019 |
| 3 | N | 01/01/2019 | 01/02/2019 |

For row 3 Col1 is still picking N because it has freeze the observation.

One solution that I can think is save the previous day file and if value is present in Col3 then pick previous day file value else new day file value. Issue with this approach is I have to save the file and the data I am working on is huge so it's not feasible. 
Is there any other way I can achieve?

Comment: The question is too broad. You have to describe the process of updating, add some context. Is it appropriate to use a mask? is it possible to pass only part of data to update? Is the data updated automatically according to a schedule or manually? What can you control in this process?

Comment: So the data gets updated automatically daily n everyday new I'd are generated with new values and if there is any change in previous I'd it will get updated automatically.